# Conditional Assignment based on value of randomized array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, conditional-statements

I'm calling an image file which is randomly sampled from a set of five, like so:

```
var image = jsPsych.randomization.sampleWithoutReplacement(['1',
'2',
'3',
'4',
'5'
])
```

The first/second/third/fourth/fifth image will be called later on in the script.

In the later part of the script, I also want to call the name that corresponds to the image.

I tried this:

```
if (image == '1') {
    name = 'one'
} else if (image == '2') {
    name = 'two'
} else if (image == '3') {
    name = 'three'
} else if (image == '4') {
    name = 'four'
} else {
    name = 'five'
};
```

I later call these variables in some HTML code like so:

```
<img src="./img/'+ image[0] +'.png" width="65" height="65" id="pfpOutput">'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<div class="headerRight css-1dbjc4n">'+
                                        '<div class="userinfo css-1dbjc4n">'+
                                            '<div class="nameContainer css-1dbjc4n">'+
                                                '<span class="name" id="nameOutput">'+name+'</span>'
```

Needless to say, this does not work and just calls 'five'.

Is there a way to ensure that whichever randomly sampled 'image' is called alongside its corresponding name in this code?

Comment: do you need both, a number and a name? how do you organize the related information/questions/answers?

Comment: I need the image and the name to match up and they are called in the same piece of code. I call the image using the img src tag and ```+ image[0]+``` and then use a similar approach for the name. I need the image/name combination to be randomised. Does that make sense?

Comment: but why take an array for just numbers (and then as strings)?

Comment: Is the thing returned by `sampleWithoutReplacement` the same for each number? So whenerver `'1'` gets picked then `image` becomes the same value? If so, check for that value, not for the number.

Comment: The number corresponds to an image which is called in an img tag. I need the image and the corresponding name to appear in the same appear at the same time.

Comment: I added an example to clarify what I mean.